# Reading XML node from C# when it's a resource in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having some trouble with the following. I'm a beginner, which is probably why.

I have a listbox that displays some pictures, it gets the paths of these pictures from an XML file. This XML file is defined as a resource in XAML. If a picture is selected and the user presses enter, I want to launch an external app with some parameters, including a path found in another node of that XML file (appath in the example below).

XML layout:

```
<picture>
   <path></path>
   <appath></appath>
</picture>
```

I can't seem to find the way to access the node from C#.
Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have any attributes in the picture node (an id of some sort) you, have to first match up on the path which you should already have in your listbox, then return the appath.

```
static string GetAppath(string xmlString, string picPath)
    {
        string appath = String.Empty;
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.LoadXml(xmlString);

        XmlNodeList xList = xDoc.SelectNodes("/picture");
        foreach (XmlNode xNode in xList)
        {
            if (xNode["path"].InnerText == picPath)
            {
                appath = xNode["appath"].InnerText;
                break;
            }
        }
        return appath;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your xml file looks something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<pictures>
 <picture>
   <path></path>
   <appath></appath>
 </picture>
</pictures>
```

If your resource name is Pictures:

```
XElement resource = XElement.Parse(Properties.Resources.Pictures);
```

Using these extensions: (just copy the class/file into your root directory of your project) http://searisen.com/xmllib/extensions.wiki

```
public class PicturesResource
{
    XElement self;
    public PicturesResource()
    { self = XElement.Parse(Properties.Resources.Pictures); }

    public IEnumerable<Picture> Pictures
    { get { return self.GetEnumerable("picture", x => new Picture(x)); } }
}

public class Picture
{
    XElement self;
    public Pictures(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

    public string Path { get { return self.Get("path", string.Empty); } }
    public string AppPath { get { return self.Get("apppath", string.Empty); } }

}
```

You could then bind the Pictures or do a look up on them:

```
PicturesResource pictures = new PicturesResource();
foreach(Picture pic in pictures.Pictures)
{
    string path = pic.Path;
    string apppath = pic.AppPath;
}
```

Or searching for a particular picture:

```
Picture pic = pictures.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Path = "some path");
if(pic != null)
{
    // do something with pic
}
```